# How to keep the textbox value while moving to the next page without using local storage?

Tags: jquery, textbox

Hai every one i have a 2 **textbox** and 1 **button** in `page1.html`.when click into the the button it redirect into the `page2.html`.In `page2.html` i press the back button it goes to the `page1.html`.When moving to the page1 i need to get the textbox value what i have enterd.Anybody
 kindly guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use some form of Javascript, as HTML doesn't contain a way of controlling values between pages.  This is either client scripted, server-side coded or browser feature.

To do it in Javascript (without JQuery), look at something like [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html).  I'm not sure why you don't want to do jQuery, it will make some things easier.  In case you change your mind, there's plenty of [cookie](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugins available for it.

jQuery method is here: [jQuery BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/).

Answer (score 0):

As long as textboxes are not hidden and were created before load event, they will retain value.

If for some reason you don't want to show them to users than you can trick to have textboxes with positioned absolute, but setting left = -99999px. This will hide them from screen.